# Could not find module FindOpenCV.cmake

Tags: linux, opencv

I am connected to a virtual linux machine where I don't have any privilege...
I installed opencv with

`cadenv opencv`

(very nice....someone else did all the job for me).

now I am trying to run a simple code to show an image

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

anc compile it with cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

when I run cmake .
I get

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  Could not find module FindOpenCV.cmake or a configuration file for package
  OpenCV.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindOpenCV.cmake or set OpenCV_DIR to the
  directory containing a CMake configuration file for OpenCV.  The file will
  have one of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I dont know this environment so I dont know how to tell Cmake where it can find what it looks for...
can you help me?

Thanks

OUTPUT FROM INSTALLATION

```
Package OpenCV release 2.4.8 has been installed.

 You can now:
 - use the commands:
     opencv_createsamples, opencv_haartraining,
     opencv_performance and opencv_traincascade.

 - use pkg-config to obtain information about compiler
   and linker flags by placing the directory
       /cadappl/opencv/2.4.8/lib/pkgconfig
   in the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH and
   using package 'opencv' as package name.

 - let CMake obtain information about OpenCV from the
   files /cadappl/opencv/2.4.8/share/OpenCV/OpenCV*.cmake;

 - View sample source files that use OpenCV in the folder
   /cadappl/opencv/2.4.8/share/OpenCV/samples and its
   subfolders c, cpp, gpu and ocl.

 - Use OpenCV from Java 1.7.0 (/usr/bin/java) by using
   /cadappl/opencv/2.4.8/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-248.jar
   which at requires the shared library
   /cadappl/opencv/2.4.8/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java248.so

 Note: all OpenCV 2.4.8 programs & libraries have been
       compiled with the GNU C compiler 4.4.7 (/usr/bin/gcc).
```

Comment: just curious, *what* did it actually install ? you won't be able to use cmake without the src tree, probably.

Comment: @berak I added what I got after the installation

Comment: good ! try pointing cmake at the resp. folder: cmake -D CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/cadappl/opencv/2.4.8/share/OpenCV

Comment: should I type this line in the command line?

Comment: i guess so, yes. - you ran cmake before, and it complained not finding files, right ? just add those args to the cmake part to make it find them